# Отображение сайта по разному для администратора и для пользователя. Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть сайт на Битриксе, когда вошёл на сайт администратором содержимое сайта выглядит одним образом. если перейти на сайт как обычный пользователь, то часть стилей css не применяется, т.е. сайт выглядит по другому. Чистил кэш битрикса и браузера - не помогло. Не пойму в чём причина? Может быть стили отваливаются?
Тут если как админ
http://prntscr.com/l3jyz1
    Тут если как пользователь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас стили неправильно подключены, нужно что бы они брались из основного css файла

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

В битриксе есть такая штука, как кеш компонентов. На эти грабли натыкались, натыкаются и будут натыкаться ещё многие начинающие и не очень пользователи битрикс.

Если вы залогинитесь админом -- вы видите версию сайта без кеша. Как только разлогинились -- тут же видите старую версию. Да просто откройте рядом приватную вкладку и посмотрите, что сайт выглядит в старой версии css.

Поэтому, на этапе разработки принято выключать кеширование компонентов.

В админке: настройки - настройки продукта - автокеширование. Отключить ВСЕ ВИДЫ кеширования на всех трёх вкладках.

[image: Настройки автокеширования битрикс]

Для тех же, кто разрабатывает прямо на продакшене, могу напомнить следующее. Кнопка "сбросить кеш" видна только залогиненным пользователям и не действует на незалогиненных пользователей.

[image: Кнопка сбросить кеш]

Для того, чтобы почистить кеш для незалогиненных пользователей -- в админке заходите в настройки автокеширования (выше писал как зайти) и на закладке Очистка файлов кеша чистим всё.

Ну и помните: [при типовых настройках] через полчаса кеш протухнет и всё само придёт в согласованное положение, если вы ничего нового не допиливали. 
Это на случай если вы не хотите давать вашим новостникам кнопку сброса кеша и просто говорите им, что через полчаса всё будет видно.

Всё остальное, что не помогло с кешем -- обращайтесь к разработчикам вашего конкретного сайта, либо если вы сами являетесь разработчиком сайта -- прикладывайте ваш код, потому что телепаты как обычно в отпуске.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло решить мою проблему!

Answer (score -1):

Вполне возможно, что верстальщик что делал тему работал из под админа и вносил все изменения в CSS файл, который подключается для поддержки панели администратора.

И естественно для обычного пользователя этот файл не подключается, а значит стили не работают.

Проверить это можно посмотрев в каких файлах прописаны стили для указанных блоков.

Comment: /bitrix/templates/.default/components/bitrix/catalog/template2/bitrix/catalog.top/.default/section/style.min.css?145495728324431*/ в админке вот отсюда подкачиваются стили

Comment: что делать?....