# Как в админке 1С-битрикс удалить информацию в шаблонах и прописать новую

Tags: битрикс

Ранее у меня была проблема, в админке меняю заголовок сайта в браузере не обновлялся. Мне посоветовали очистить кэш в админке битрикса и браузера... все сделал ,но до сих пор стоит старая информация в заголовке сайта.
Кто нибудь из посетителей этого форума мог бы мне помочь. 
Как на админке 1с битрикс прописать новую информацию в шаблонах, заголовок сайта изменить на новый. Чтоб на браузере тоже поменялся.???

Comment: кэш удаляли в браузере и самом битриксе?

Comment: Спасибо что ответили,да на браузере удалил кэш. Если удалить кэш на админке битрикс это не повлияет ли на работу сайта?

Comment: нисколько не повлияет: кэш битрикс и так [по умолчанию через полчаса протухает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494919/213987). А на будущее: самый простой способ проверить кэш браузера - открыть приватную вкладку.

Comment: Спасибо, кэш на битрекс тоже очистел. Не помогло. Меняю заголовок а на браузере выходить старая информация. Может дела в хостинге? Может надо перезаписать все файлы?

Comment: @Тимур, вряд ли. Посмотрите, тот ли заголовок правите. Может быть так, что исправили заголовок одной страницы, а была открыта другая. Второе - посмотрите, куда пишется заголовок страницы после сохранения. Если в базу данных - проверьте, сохранились ли результаты. Для удобства работы с базой данных можете воспользоваться phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Спасибо вам Kosmos ,прислушаюсь вашему совету.

Comment: В каких шаблонах хотите удалить информацию? Каким образом у вас устанавливается заголовок страницы? Прописан ли код `$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false);`? Вы не даете никакой полезной информации, которая помогла бы решить вопрос.